# Partial grouping of certain rows and updating the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this

```
PCode     Stage     Score
--------------------------------
P123       1         3
P123       2         2
P123       3         1
P123       4         3
P123       5         0
P458       1         2
P458       2         1
P458       3         3
P458       4         3
P458       5         0
P624       1         1
P624       2         2
P624       3         0
P624       4         1
P624       5         2
P792       1         3
P792       2         0
P792       3         2
P792       4         1
P792       5         3
-----------------------------
```

My requirement is to group rows of stage 4 and 5 and take the least score of those and make it as the new stage 4 data. Like this

```
PCode     Stage     Score
--------------------------------
P123       1         3
P123       2         2
P123       3         1
P123       4         0
P458       1         2
P458       2         1
P458       3         3
P458       4         0
P624       1         1
P624       2         2
P624       3         0
P624       4         1
P792       1         3
P792       2         0
P792       3         2
P792       4         1
-----------------------------
```

So there won't be a 5th stage row and 4th stage is the grouped least of 4th and 5th

This is the way I tried which is working fine, but not sure is there any better/optimal solution

```
declare @test table(Pcode varchar(20),stage int,score int)
insert into @test (Pcode,stage,score) values('p123',1,3),('p123',2,3),('p123',3,3),('p123',4,3),('p123',5,3)
,('p458',1,3),('p458',2,0),('p458',3,1),('p458',4,0),('p458',5,2)
,('p678',1,0),('p678',2,3),('p678',3,2),('p678',4,1),('p678',5,1)
,('p156',1,3),('p156',2,2),('p156',3,2),('p156',4,1),('p156',5,2)
,('p458',1,3),('p458',2,0),('p458',3,1),('p458',4,0),('p458',5,2)

select * from(
select * from @test where stage not in (4,5)
union all
select Pcode,4,min(score) from @test  where stage in (4,5) group by Pcode)tbl order by Pcode,stage
```

Answer (score 2):

As a query, you can do:

```
select pcode,
       (case when stage in (4, 5) then 4 else stage end) as stage,
       min(score)
from t
group by pcode,
         (case when stage in (4, 5) then 4 else stage end);
```

If you want to change the table, then it is a bit trickier.  I would suggest an `update` and a `delete`:

```
update t4
    set score = (case when score_5 < score then score_5 else score end)
    from (select t.*, 
                 max(case when stage = 5 then score end) over (partition by pcode) as score_5
          from t
         ) t4
    where stage = 4;

delete from t
    where stage = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query using union all

```
declare @test table(Pcode varchar(20),stage int,score int)
insert into @test (Pcode,stage,score) values('p123',1,3),('p123',2,3),('p123',3,3),('p123',4,3),('p123',5,3)
,('p458',1,3),('p458',2,0),('p458',3,1),('p458',4,0),('p458',5,2)
,('p678',1,0),('p678',2,3),('p678',3,2),('p678',4,1),('p678',5,1)
,('p156',1,3),('p156',2,2),('p156',3,2),('p156',4,1),('p156',5,2)
,('p458',1,3),('p458',2,0),('p458',3,1),('p458',4,0),('p458',5,2)


select * from @test where stage in (1,2,3)
union ALL
select pcode, '4' stage, min(score) from #test where stage in (4,5)
group by pcode

order by Pcode, stage
```